# What happens when a lich uses the Blackstaff?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, undead

The description of the [*Blackstaff*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/blackstaff) magic item in the *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist* adventure (p. 190) states:

> When the Blackstaff dies, the spirit of that individual becomes trapped in the staff along with the spirits of the previous Blackstaffs.

If a lich is worthy enough to attune to the staff, then when it dies, does the Blackstaff have precedent over the lich's phylactery?

Comment: Huh, that description makes the Blackstaff sound insidious. I could have sworn in earlier editions it was a copy of the mind/spirit/intellect that was stored in the staff/tower to help the future Blackstaff

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to a lich's soul when it dies with a Ring of Mind Shielding?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163475/what-happens-to-a-lichs-soul-when-it-dies-with-a-ring-of-mind-shielding)

Answer (score 6):

## Probably not

We have a very similar [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163475/what-happens-to-a-lichs-soul-when-it-dies-with-a-ring-of-mind-shielding?rq=1) about a *ring of mind shielding*, and the same reasoning applies here.  Liches do not die when their bodies are destroyed, so the blackstaff does not trigger.  Also, a lich's soul is already stored in the phylactery (and not in its body), so stuff that tries to take a lich's soul from its body is unlikely to work.